# Set GPLinearUnit type parameter default based on input spatial reference (Buffer Example)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, python-toolbox, units

Within a .pyt python toolbox I'd like to have a parameter of data type GPLinearUnit get a default value based on an input Feature Class (FC). The standard Buffer (Analysis) tool works as a great example of what I'm trying to imitate:

[image: Desired User Input]

The closest I've been able to come is to set units in updateParameters based on the FC spatialReference.linearUnitName, but linearUnitName and GPLinearUnit units aren't the same and there are [50+ linear units](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/003r/pdf/projected_coordinate_systems.pdf). Anyone know a better way to do this or a reference/code somewhere I could at least pull the linearUnitName to GPLinearUnit from?

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    inFC = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayname = "Input FC",
        name = "inputFC",
        datatype = "DEFeatureClass",
        parameterType = "Required",
        direction = "input")
    units = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Distance & Units",
        name="Units",
        datatype="GPLinearUnit",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction = "Input")
    params = [inFC, units]
    return params

def updateParameters(self, params):
    if not params[1].altered and params[0].altered:
        spRef=arcpy.Describe(params[0].valueAsText).spatialReference
        if spRef.linearUnitName == "Foot_US":
            params[1].values = "0 Feet"
    return
```

I should also point out that this code defaults the distance to 0, where as the Buffer tool I'm imitating is able to set units without a distance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In getParameterInfo, set a dependency between the two parameters.

`units.parameterDependencies = [inFC.name]`

Comment: I was hoping there was a parameterDependencies based solution, just couldn't find the right property. .name is usually used to return a string for the naming of the input (i.e. I would have expected this to give "L:\Projected_FC.shp") can you offer any explanation why it works?

Comment: Parameter dependencies are used for many of these types of relationships. To go back to your original observation that Buffer showed this behavior, you can observe this by testing Buffer's own parameters. For instance:

arcpy.GetParameterInfo('buffer_analysis')[2].parameterDependencies --> which returns [0]. 

You can see the distance parameter has a relationship with the input (here it shows the parameter by index, while in a python toolbox it is handled by parameter name).

Comment: How can we restrict users to the linear units of the feature class? I followed this great advice, but can still change units to something different. I can't seem to get parameter[2].value.Unit to return anything. Online it says Unit is a property of GPLinearUnit.